# How does one search for questions and answer by specific user and by date?

Tags: support, search

I have recently had a maths puzzle I got stuck on. I am nearly 100% sure that I've seen the answer to this question on this site. I only know potential users that might have asked/answered the question **and** potential dates it might have been asked. Is it possible to search for all question and answers for a specific user asked on specific dates?

Say I want to see all question/answers asked by user Bernie on date 3 January to 16 January 2015.

Answer (score 5):

Use the query

```
user:123456 created:2015-01-03..2015-01-16
```

where 123456 is replaced by Bernie's account number.

If you know if it's a question or answer add `is:q` or `is:a`

For more options and details see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Comment: Maybe it is useful to mention also that search modifier [user:me](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame) restricts the search to *my own* posts. And if you go to [a user profile](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) then the `user:userid` part is already prefilled in the top bar. (And this is also the way to find userid.) Let me know whether you prefer that I post a separate answer with adding these details or whether you add them to your own post.