# Ordering the questions of a day

Tags: discussion, support, search

When we order the questions by votes, we see questions from all past years and days.

There are a way to see the questions of today ( or of a given day or period?) ordered by votes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you include [created:2018-04-05](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3a2018-04-05) in your search query, you see the *posts* which were created today. You can restrict it to questions using [created:2018-04-05 is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3a2018-04-05+is:q). (Naturally, if you try the same thing tomorrow, you'll have to change the date to see new questions.) There is a shortcut [created:1d](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3a1d) which only returns posts created yesterday - I do not know whether there is something similar for the posts created today.

And, of course you can use any other date (or date range), for example [created:2018-01-01..2018-01-01 is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3a2018-01-01..2018-01-01+is:q) returns questions from January 1 2018. You can also further refine the search query, for example, you can only search for questions [in a specific tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3a2018-01-01..2018-01-01+is:q+[general-topology]).

Of course, as with any search, you have several possibilities how to order search results. One of them is by score. So you can see the top-voted:

- [posts created today](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2018-04-05);
- [questions created today](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2018-04-05+is:q);
- [questions created yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a1d%20is%3aq);
- [questions created on January 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2018-01-01..2018-01-01%20is%3aq);
- [questions from January 1 in general-topology tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2018-01-01..2018-01-01%20is%3aq+[general-topology]); etc.

For more details see Advanced Search Options [in search help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Here is also a related older posts: [How does one search for questions and answer by specific user and by date?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25386)

Comment: `created:1d..` is posts created yesterday or today.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I am not sure about that. If you indeed try to [search using this option](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=created%3a1d%20is%3aq), you can see above the search results this text "search options questions only created 2018-04-04 - 2018-04-04". And [the help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) explicitly says that *1y, 1m, and 1d are shorthand for "last year", "last month", and "yesterday".*

Comment: My point was that *in addition* to `created:1d` there is `created:1d..`. Compare the results from your search with the results from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A1d..+is%3Aq).

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I did not notice the dots.

Comment: A good feature would be to make this (and other search strings) obvious when searching; advanced search etc.

Comment: @ProducerofBS Try to [search for something](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=test). If you do that, you are displayed a link called *Advanced Search Tips*. After you click on it, you are displayed the most frequent search modifiers. And below them is link to the help page which describes more options.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks. I always half wondered where it was but never made the effort to find out. I should probably have emphasised "make obvious" more.

Answer (score 6):

Go to [moderation tools -> stats -> today](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Stats&daterange=today)

It has most upvoted, downvoted, commented, etc. posts.

N.B. this is only for [10k+ rep users](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).